# Swing: What is a good way to implement fully-scalable components?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, layout, scaling

I am creating an application which has a scrollable and scalable (zoomable) view. Inside this view I want to place other components (most of them customized `JPanel`s and `JInternalFrame`s).

Things such as fonts and borders, and sub-elements such as buttons **don't** need to be scalable. Only dimensions and position of container components should be.

What do you think, **what is a good way to implement scalable components?**

**EDIT:** I'm talking about resizing the **entire layout** including all
components. Please think of something such as a visual UML editor with zoom functionality.

My alternatives are:

- Create a custom layout manager;
- Create custom resizeable sub-components;
- Create a custom container which would take care of resizing its sub-components;
- Do something else?

Possible problems:

- Boilerplate code;
- Necessity to provide access to additional custom properties of components;
- Not straightforward (inconsistent) representation of components in code.
- Something else?

Comment: what do you mean by "scalable"? Do you mean components which re-size?

Comment: And are you taking about how to do the layout so that component scales or actually your own scalable custom components?

Comment: Given the talk about zooming, I'm pretty sure he means resizing the entire layout including all components. Think Flash.

Comment: Can you provide us with a screenshot/conceptual image? Might help understand your intention.

Comment: I can't. Please think of something such as a visual UML editor with zoom functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is why layout managers exist: they tell contained components where and how large they should be.

Since you're talking about a UML editor, are you using contained Swing components to represent the various objects in the diagram (eg, a component for a class)? If yes, then you've got a lot of work ahead of you (although it's not necessarily a bad approach). I'd recommend creating a constraints object that identifies the object's location on a "unit space," then multiplying by the current size.

Answer (score 1):

I've done that by creating a custom layout manager. Every component (or rather component class) on the frame has a marker whether or not it shall be resized when the container is resized (e.g. tables are resized, buttons are not). Those which are not resized are moved when the container is resized.

This is used to make resizeable forms without any manual setup, i.e. forms are defined by  just specifying x/y/length/width for each component (no further alignment info).

Answer (score 0):

If I look at this problem as visual UML editor then I had to think about single "canvas" component drawing each element as graphical object with base aspect ration and zooming in/out. I can't see reason for list of components aligned within parent container.

Comment: I want to use Swing for most components, so I can't just "draw" them in a scaled way (would look ugly).

Comment: We do not understand each other. I was just pointing to your justification for visual UML editor.

Answer (score 0):

I started a similar solution that works fine without touching the original layout.

It's as easy as this:

```
// Install scalable layout and CTRL+/CTRL- keys for scaling operations
ScalableLayoutUtils.installScalableLayoutAndKeys(new DefaultScalableLayoutRegistry(),  frame, 0.1);
```

It's still under work but It will be soon available as part of the next "utils4swing" version.