# Swing popup located at bottom right of windows screen

Tags: windows, swing, popup

I wish to make a swing popup window which appears at the bottom right of the windows screen. The problem is that windows has a toolbar at the bottom which takes up some space, so I don't know how to work out the y location for the popup so that it does not overlap the toolbar at the bottom of screen.

== Update, must be Java Swing, thanks! ==

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031795/swing-what-is-a-good-way-to-implement-fully-scalable-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
    yourPopUpWindow.setLocation(WIDTH, WIDTH);
```